# RTCAudioSession.h and some other files are missing in newly built WebRTC.framwork(iOS)

Tags: ios, build, webrtc, apprtc

I am trying to build WebRTC to get updated library file. I have successfully
built the framework.There is a demo in the source code.
At first I am trying to run demo app(AppRTCMobile) with the built framework.Problem is that some files are missing in the framework.
It is targeting to import some files from webrtc/modules/audiodevice/ios/obj and showing error for not to be able to import the files.So I can't run the demo and continue afterwards.
I followed the below link to build WebRTC:
https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/
Can Aynone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTCAudioSession.h is never included in WebRTC.framwork, hope it may include soon.

Possible workaround's:
Remove/comment RTCAudioSession related stuff in ARDVideoCallViewController
OR manually add RTCAudioSession.h file in WebRTC.framwork/Headers/

Comment: how can we add RTCAudioSession.h file manually in the project, I do add the file in the project but it shows me the error ""_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCAudioSession", referenced from:"